# how to use password with PBEKeySpec hash

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm working on an embedded application, and I need to decrypt a message using PBEKeySpec, since the password is a hash, I don't know if the algorithm is correct, because I always have a return similar to this: '?s.PH ?~+? ?*ol XL >?? ;#??????'

```
public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {

    byte[] original = null;
    try {            
        char[] pw = getSecret().toCharArray();

        byte[] salt = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pw, salt, 1000, 384);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 0, key, 0, 32);
        System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 32, iv, 0, 16);

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);

        original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted.getBytes());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String(original, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
}
```

To generate the password hash:

```
  private static String getSecret() {
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        byte[] hash = digest.digest(Arrays.copyOf(secret.getBytes(), 36));

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hexString.append('0');
            }
            hexString.append(hex);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CriptografiaHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}
```

Comment: We don't know what the protocol is. If it requires a hash of a password instead of directly using PBKDF2 then somebody did some strange engineering and all bets are off. I would however question if extending the 32 byte hash with 4 zero valued bytes or if using the *hexadecimal encoding* instead of the bytes of the hash directly would be in **any** sensible protocol. In the end, keys are random binary values, so if you try and directly convert to characters then sure, the output seems random enough to me (the question marks are just replaced unknown characters).

Comment: In the end, the proof is in the pudding: if you are able to decrypt a ciphertext with PKCS#7 compatible padding (i.e. `"PKCS5Padding"` in Java) then it is very likely that you succeeded.